# Android app crash Error: Missing Realm constructor. Did you run "pod install"? in react native android

Tags: android, react-native, realm

Previously we used react-native 0.66.4 and realm 10.21.1. Then we updated our project into react-native 0.72.4 and realm 12.1.0. Newly build android apps are working fine without any issues. But old users (used react-native 0.66.4 and realm 10.21.1) are facing crash issue after upgrade(react-native 0.72.4 and realm 12.1.0) the android apps

```
Previous version
react-native - 0.66.4
realm - 10.21.1

Upgrade version
react-native - 0.72.4
realm - 12.1.0
```

Comment: There's not a lot for us to go on in the question; *facing crash* is a bit vague. What kind of crash? When does it happen? Did you do some troubleshooting? Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)